# how to create graph (data structure) using linked lists

Tags: data-structures, graph

I have create my linked list and I need to create a graph without using dictionaries and normal lists, i have to use linked list, how anyone recommended me to build it? my linked list looks like this:

```
class LinkList:

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None
    self.count = int()

def add(self, value):
    if not self.head:
        self.head = Node(value)
        self.tail = self.head
    else:
        self.tail.next = Node(value)
        self.tail = self.tail.next
    self.count += 1

def get(self, position):
    node = self.head
    for i in range(position):
        if node:
            node = node.next
    if not node:
        return "posicion no encontrada"
    else:
        return node.value

def delete_first(self):
    if self.head is None:
        print("lista vacia, imposible eliminar primer elemento")
    elif self.head == self.tail:
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count -= 1
        print("habia un elemento, lista vacia")
    else:
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.count -= 1

def delete_last(self):
    if self.tail is None:
        print("lista vacia, imposible eliminar ultimo elemento")
    elif self.head == self.tail:
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count -= 1
        print("habia un elemento, lista vacia")
    else:
        validate = True
        temp = self.head
        while validate:
            if temp.next == self.tail:
                self.tail = temp
                self.count -= 1
                validate = False
            else:
                temp = temp.next

def delete(self, number):
    temp = self.head
    temp2 = self.head
    if self.head is None:
        print("Lista vacia, imposible eliminar elemento")
    else:
        if self.head.value == number:
            self.delete_first()
        elif self.tail.value == number:
            self.delete_last()
        else:
            validate = True
            while validate:
                temp = temp.next
                if temp.value == number:
                    temp2.next = temp.next
                    self.count -= 1
                    validate = False
                elif self.tail == temp:
                    print("El elemento no esta en la lista")
                    validate = False
                temp2 = temp2.next

def __repr__(self):
    if self.head is None:
        return str("[]")
    rep = '['
    actual_node = self.head
    while actual_node:
        if actual_node != self.tail:
            rep += '{0},'.format(actual_node.value)
        else:
            rep += '{0}]'.format(actual_node.value)
            break
        actual_node = actual_node.next

    return rep
```

Comment: what kind of graph are you seeking to create?  do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve with a graph data structure?

Comment: I need to map a "network" the way it works is like this:

You start at "port 0 (node)" and each node/port has connections (max 7) to other ports

So I need to build a tree or graph while I'm travelling thru the "network" so I can keep track of my path to the final port (known) and after that show my path on a txt file. The restrictions of my assignment are not to use default lists, dictionaries, tuples, etc.. so i built a linked list and I need to create the tree or graph with them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a graph data structure, you need to modify your linked list so that each node has a pointer to multiple nodes.  Since you have a max of 7 connections, this could be an array with the list of connections.

Instead of just having node.next, you might have an array of connections, like node.links where you would add a link to connect a node to any other node in the graph.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How would you modify my linked list so each node has pointer to multiples nodes? is it like a doubled linked list kinda?(I edit so you can see my code know)